# Bootstrap static resource is not applying to page

Tags: visualforce, static-resources

This is the VF page I am trying to style

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" controller="ComposeEmailController">
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'sf-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.PenrodScripts, 'PenrodScripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js')}" />
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'sf-bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js')}"/>
<!-- <apex:stylesheet value="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/> -->

<div class="container">
<h1>Compose Vitality Email</h1>
<apex:form styleClass="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fromAddress">From Address </label>
        <apex:selectList value="{!fromAddress}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="fromAddress" styleClass="form-control">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!fromAddresses}"/>
        </apex:selectList>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="toAddress">To Address </label>
        <apex:inputText value="{!email}" id="toAddress" styleClass="form-control"/>
    </div>
</apex:form>
</div>
```

Here is the static resource:
[image]

When I uncomment the bootstrap cdn the styles are applied. But they are not being applied through the static resource

The browser is importing the sheet, it just will not be applied.

[image]

Comment: It is easy to add an extra level of directory to the ZIP. Suggest you double check by unzipping.

Comment: Are you recommending adding a subdirectory? Or are you saying double check there is not a subdirectory?

Comment: @JoeyThomaschaske Check to see if there's a parent folder, as Keith said. Also, see if you can access the resource directly by going to /resource/bootstrap/sf-bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css -- you should see the raw file in your browser if your path is correct.

Comment: Double check there is not.

Comment: So I just included a screenshot of the browser importing the stylesheet @sfdcfox

Comment: Pity it is chopped off just before what is hopefully sf-bootstrap. But the fact its in that view means its been requested at least somewhere. Double check in the "Network" tab of your browser that all requested resources were found. But if it is being loaded then it not being applied is puzzling.

Comment: @JoeyThomaschaske I belive KeithC is right and you may be using namespaced version of sf-bootstrap. Please try to add one more div tag above your container and give it `class="bootstrap "` and `setHeader="false"`  and `standardstylesheets="false"` in the  apex:page tag and check if it works. Also a full screenshot of the resource panel along with network panel will be helpful.

Comment: We decided to just go with the cdn since it does work and it's cost effective.